# Why would an alien race want to experiment on all primitive life in the galaxy?

Tags: interspecies-relations

950,000 years ago, a race of intelligent reptilian species, known as the erubians evolved on their home planet of Erub. They are a type 2 civilization, and have technologically marvels that even the most forward thinking human could never dream of. Faster than light travel, infinite energy converters, replicators, 10,000 year lifespans. But, the erubians have not invented anything new for 80 millennia.

The Erubians often experiment on “lesser” intelligent beings e.g. Pre-type 1 species. In 2500 bc years ago, they found a small planet orbiting a yellow star, populated by intelligent apes. The experiment they did on these creatures was to start a crude nuclear war between two  opposing large tribes, that pathetically fought over an abstract idea. Anyway my question is, what would be a good motivation for a type 2 civilization to experiment on primitive societies.

I was the one who made that question. I have had many different profiles. I am Jayden Harris, Bryan, Bryan 2 and etc.

Comment: Too much grant money?

Comment: Despite their power and intelligence, they are still enslaved to their emotions? Possibly because those who started to abolish their emotions became nothing more than will-less automatons. And just like grownups might enjoy seeing a few dogs fight and bet on it, or enjoy sports/E-sports competitions, these might enjoy it on a larger scale.

Comment: @Canyon Runner not sure about the multiple accounts, but that just might be against TOS. Not sure though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too story-based.  This isn't a question about the rules of your world (or civilization), it's a question about the plot of your story.  No one answer can be any better than any other (no right answer).  Frankly, the motivaton for such an action could and should be one of the mysteries of your story the reader will enjoy having solved.  Since that makes the issue 100% a plot device, it's a story-based question and therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they can organize reality shows, and with their advanced technology put invisible cameras everywhere. At their whim they can separate factions, start wars, make stories, unfold them. For them, living so long, a lifespan of a human-like creature is nothing, so they could literally follow certain people through their life. Take that person in secrecy, make him have some special abilities to change his life, and put him back into the society and see what happens, or advance some of the people to see their behavior, or whatever else. Possibilities are endless.

That would be a REAL Reality show! I would definitely pay cable for that.

Answer (score 1):

**They are religious, and worship by interacting with creation.**

> Job 12:7-10. “But ask the animals, and they will teach you, or the
>   birds in the sky, and they will tell you; 8 or speak to the earth, and
>   it will teach you, or let the fish in the sea inform you. 9 Which of
>   all these does not know that the hand of the LORD has done this? 10 In
>   his hand is the life of every creature and the breath of all mankind.

[image: kinetic sculpture]
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/512636370053763103/

Imagine a kinetic sculpture on the grounds of a museum.  You and your family wander within it.  The kids push it and climb on it.  You marvel at how the artist has arranged it and the code behind it.  You see how other visitors have interacted.  Maybe you take away something of the artist - her intent, or message, or sense of humor, or her engineering finesse.

So too Creation: all that there is.  Your aliens are the lords of Creation, set above it all by their Creator.  How to worship such a Creator?  Creation is knowable.  Learn from and marvel at the Creator by investigating and interacting with infinite and infinitely complex creation.<sup>*</sup>

Your aliens will be more interesting if they interact with creation on all levels.  The nuclear war is sort of the "burning ants with a magnifying glass" extreme, but include interactions and investigations on all other levels as well.  That is what they do.

*<sup>this principle might have broader applications.</sup>